# Java web application memory handling

Tags: java, database, jsp, memory

I have a Java web application which uses Hibernate for storing data into the database and retrieving them.

The strategy I am currently using is to load everything from the database on to the application at start up, and saving/updating them to the database as the user interacts with the application.

What I have also done is to keep track of Transaction history for each user as part of the business logic. (So this transaction history is all loaded on application start up).

The problem I can see is that I shouldn't load all the transaction history for all the user, because if there are a lot of the Transaction history, and users might not necessarily need to see them, then that could be a lot of memory being used up, so it is not efficient.

I was wondering if there is something similar to what PHP script can do, which is just query the database only when user request to see the transaction history, and so it is not using the server resource. (Asides from query the database) Or what are some suggestions/comments regards to what I am facing right now.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not just query Hibernate when you need a given piece of information?

Comment: Actually, yes. That was kind of silly.
But say, for example, I have a large piece of data, and it is needed frequently, then is it better to save it on memory? What to do in that case?

Comment: Tell Hibernate that and let it manage the caching.

Comment: Okay, so if I understand it correctly, then I should continue saving things into my database. When user request information, then I query Hibernate and present the information back to the user. And finally, I should take out the part where I am pulling information from the database back to the Entity, unless the business logic needs it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query Hibernate when you need a given piece of information and let Hibernate manage putting it back to the database.  This will allow Hibernate to manage the caching.

Note, that when using Hibernate, you should let Hibernate manage the data completely.  Do not add or change data yourself using raw SQL.

If you are using a modern container, you should consider migrating to JPA as it is the standard in Java EE containers, allowing you to be more flexible when you need to scale.  JPA is very close to Hibernate, but is an API, not an implementation, so you have more than one to choose from.

Comment: Perhaps I am not understanding Hibernate correctly. I currently have a session open, update, commit, and close, in this order, every time I update the Object/Entity properties. I thought this would prevent the database from going out of synch with the current state of the program. But what you are suggesting is to let the session stay opened, so that the Object is persistent and update, commit, and close the session when user closes the session/log off?

Comment: I am not intimately familiar with Hibernate.  What does the Hibernate documentation suggest you do in this situation?

Comment: I actually just looked this up, there are two approaches to this, one is what I am currently using; session per operation, and the other is session per request. I will actually need to look into this to get a better understanding. (Although, to me, the session per operation make sense, because I need to keep the database in synch with the application. However, I can see that I am not utilizing the persistency which is offered by Hibernate)

Meanwhile, thank you for your answer and your help!

Answer (score 0):

why not query hibernate for every request come in and release after response? This is a common approach.